# Ubuntu 23 xorg issue with Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, wayland, 23.04

I have switch to Ubuntu 23 with xorg but it does not use my gpu instead it is using software rendering. It’s making me crazy could someone help me with that ?

I have tried to reinstall and my secure boot is already off.

I am using nvidia 535 with a GTX 166O SUPER